# Image resizing error in Java

Tags: java, image-resizing

Why doesn't this code resize the image according to the jLabel size? Why doesn't the image fit into the jLabel? What did I do wrong? After studying lots of code snippets about image resizing, here is the code I have done so far,

```
private void btn_browseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

    try {

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        int width = lbl_img.getWidth();
        int height = lbl_img.getHeight();
        Image image = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(buffered);
        lbl_img.setIcon(imageIcon);
        txt_imgpath.setText(filename);

        File file = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        } {
            person_image = bos.toByteArray();
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FoodsJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
private ImageIcon format = null;
String filename = null;
byte[] person_image = null;
```

This code doesn't show any exception but doesn't work as I wanted. It displays the image as it's actual size,big or small. Not as the jLabel's size. Sorry for this kind of newbie type question. I am just a beginner of Java. I tried a lot but can't figure out the solution. Anyone please help me.

Edit:
While retrieving data by clicking data from jTable or by searching through jTextField, the image display as it's actual size,big or small. Not as the jLabel's size. Do I need something to do in that code too? Here is the code,

```
private void tbl_foodsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    int raw = tbl_foods.getSelectedRow();
    String Table_Click = (tbl_foods.getModel().getValueAt(raw, 0).toString());
    try
    {
        String sql = "Select Image from Product_food where ID='"+Table_Click+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Image");
            format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
            lbl_img.setIcon(format);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {

        String sql = "Select * from Product_food where ID='"+Table_Click+"' ";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            String add1 = rs.getString("ID");
            txt_proid.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getString("Name");
            txt_name.setText(add2);
            Double add3 = rs.getDouble("Price");
            txt_price.setText(Double.toString(add3));
            Date add4 = rs.getDate("Date");
            txt_adddate.setDate(add4);
            byte[] add5 = rs.getBytes("Image");
            format = new ImageIcon(add5);
            lbl_img.setIcon(format);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is jLabel in your code?

Comment: lbl_img is the jLabel here.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it but this seems fine to me, or at least the scaling code as-pictured does. A [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. Instead of reading an image from your hard drive, you can read [an image from the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/2891664) with `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.net.URL("url.for.image"))` which makes an example self-contained so we can actually run it ourselves if we need to.

Comment: @Tabassum, I am not seeing any issue with your code as it is working as asked on my system.

Comment: I do this in new frame but still it is not working. :'(

Comment: While retrieving data by clicking data from jTable or by searching through jTextField, the image display as it's actual size,big or small. Not as the jLabel's size. Do I need something to do in that code too?

Comment: I've edited my question. Will you please check that? I have to submit my project very soon. I've been stuck in this problem for so long and now I feel like dying. Any help will be life savior for me. :(